# Retrieving data from EditText and storing it in a variable, What should be the data type of the variable?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

```
searchField.getText()
```

I want to store data of a `EditText` field in a variable. I know it returns string data but when I tried to store that in string type variable that didn't work.

As in java variables declared according to the class name,

I tried that way too. I tried `EditText varibleName = searchField.getText();` But didn't work.

can anyone explain why it didn't work and what should be the correct data type to store it?

**I need an explanation how does it works. I mean What if I don't convert it to string. and What if I want to store it as row.**

Comment: The answer is (**obviously**): `String`.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use

```
String var = searchField.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to String

```
String.valueOf(searchField.getText())
```